# How to use Bootstrap 4 in Flask-Bootstrap?

Tags: python, flask, flask-bootstrap

The automatic supplied css file of Flask-bootstrap is like this:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It is version 3. Is there any way to use bootstrap4 in flask-bootstrap? For now, I just change the css and js files to version 4 in my base template. But I am wondering if this will make some subtle problems.

Comment: There's a pull request on the flask-bootstrap for bootstrap4 support, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Bootstrap4 explicitly:

`pip install Flask_Bootstrap4`

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap-Flask](https://github.com/greyli/bootstrap-flask) is an alternative for Flask-Boostrap that supports Bootstrap 4. There is also a [migration tutorial](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html), maybe you can give it a try.